# 2 way binding not working in setTimeout callback in angular 1

Tags: angularjs, 2-way-object-databinding

I want to disable submit button during save and enable it after saved.

It is not enabling. I can see the flag changed. But the flag on the `view` is not updating as I would imagine 2 way binding should give me that.

The code as below

```
$scope.save = function (){
    $scope.saving_survey = true;
    setTimeout(function(){
        $scope.saving_survey = false;
        console.log($scope.saving_survey);
    }, 1000);

}


<button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="save()" ng-disabled="saving_survey">
    save {{saving_survey}}
</button>
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is changing scope outside of angular context...that's why there is a `$timeout` service in angular which wraps setTimeout and also invokes $apply to run a digest of view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use `$timeout` service. it should be injecte to controller

```
 $scope.save = function (){
  $scope.saving_survey = true;
   $timeout(function(){
    $scope.saving_survey = false;
    console.log($scope.saving_survey);
  }, 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically default javascript functions(setTimeout,interval,eventListener,etc) doesn't have $watch wrapper. So manually you need to trigger $watch, for that you need to call `$scope.$apply()`. Best way of calling `$apply` shown below,

```
if(!$scope.$$phase) {
    $scope.$apply();
}
```

> Note: `$$phase` return true if already digest cycle in progress else it
>   will be false